# XSD Error: Type is not declared, or is not a simple type

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

For this explanation I am using 2 different XSDs:

**customEntry.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="customEntry"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/customEntry.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/customEntry.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/customEntry.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"        
    >
  <xs:simpleType name="customEntry">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9_%./]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**element_ArtStyleSuffix.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="element_ArtStyleSuffix"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/element_ArtStyleSuffix.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/element_ArtStyleSuffix.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/element_ArtStyleSuffix.xsd"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    >
  <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/customEntry.xsd" schemaLocation="customEntry.xsd"/>

  <!-- Civilizations ArtStyleSuffix Enumeration -->
  <xs:simpleType name="enum_ArtStyleSuffix">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="_EURO"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="_AFRI"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="_AMER"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="_ASIA"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <!-- ArtStyleSuffix GameData Schema Information -->
  <xs:element name="GameData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ArtStyleSuffix">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
              Select a default ArtStyleSuffix or you may create your own custom one and place its TypeName here.
            </xs:documentation>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:union memberTypes="customEntry enum_ArtStyleSuffix"/>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My problem is with the following line:

```
<xs:union memberTypes="customEntry enum_ArtStyleSuffix"/>
```

Visual Studio 2015 community is throwing the error:

> Type 'http://tempuri.org/element_ArtStyleSuffix.xsd:customEntry' **is
>   not declared, or is not a simple type**.

It looks like a simple type to me and I thought the import line declared it, so maybe I don't understand "import" fully cause I'm not receiving any errors from the import line just the union line.  Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a simply type.  However, it is not declared in the target namespace of the current XSD; it's declared in the namespace of the imported XSD.  Reference `customEntry` in the imported `http://tempuri.org/customEntry.xsd` namespace to eliminate the error...

Specifically, declare a namespace prefix on the `xs:schema` element of your main XSD:

```
xmlns:ce="http://tempuri.org/customEntry.xsd"
```

so that you can use it in your `xs:union` declaration:

```
<xs:union memberTypes="ce:customEntry enum_ArtStyleSuffix"/>
```

and your error will go away.

**Side note**: It's acceptable, but neither required nor conventional to name your namespaces as URLs to XSD files; consider dropping the `.xsd` extension.